# Django return user model id with L

Tags: django, model

This problem did not appear until now - Here it is: When I try to get the user id from the User model it returns the user ID and the letter L.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User

>>> u = User.objects.get(username='testuser')

>>> u.id

1L
```

I believe that this is the problem when I try to use the user id as a foreign key in another table. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "L" suffix is just python telling you that it is using a large integer to represent the ID. It only affects what you see on the console, and shouldn't interfere at all with the way that python is using that number for other purposes.